# Insert from select on same table and store old and new identity values in separate table

Tags: sql, sql-server, identity

Temporary table:

```
declare @Temp_Table table
                                   (
                                        newSID int,
                                        oldSID int
                                   )
```

Database table: `Solutions`

```
Solutions:

* 1   solution1  111
* 2   solution2  111
* 3   solution3  111
```

After insert,

```
* 1   solution1  111
* 2   solution2  111
* 3   solution3  111
* 4   solution1  222
* 5   solution2  222
* 6   solution3  222
```

temp table Expected

```
  oldsID  NewSID

* 1              4
* 2              5
* 3              6
```

This table has `SID` (identity), `SName` and cnumber.

Now I want to select some rows from the `Solutions` table and insert their values into same table.

When inserting each row I want to store the old identity value and new identity value in the temporary table (`@Temp_Table`).

Please help me with this.

Comment: Google `SQL OUTPUT CLAUSE`

Comment: your question is not clear at all !! please give us the selection query you have, we can't know what are we supposed to put into `newSolutionID` and what to put into `oldSolutionID` !!

Comment: newSolutionID is the recently inserted identity value and oldSolutionID is selected rows identity values..

Comment: ex: insert into solutions (solutionname) select solutionname from solutions. (here I need to get the select statement identity values and newly inserted identity values and store them into a temp table..

Comment: I am struggling with why this a problem. You simply insert the value from your old table into the oldSolutionID column. But then I have to wonder why you need a new identity. Seems that just inserting the original value would be a LOT simpler.

Comment: The context of what you are trying to do is lost because you haven't shared enough information about the process you are attempting.

Comment: You'll get a much better answer if you provide sample data and your expected result. As of now I'm not sure why a vanilla insert won't do the trick - "INSERT INTO YOUR_TABLE SELECT Transformations_You_Want_To_Do FROM YOUR_TABLE

Comment: Please check the updated description

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to use `merge` instead of a regular `insert into..select`, since with `merge` you can use data from both the source and the target in the `output` clause.

First, create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions):

```
CREATE TABLE Solutions
(
    SolutionID int identity (1,1), 
    SolutionName varchar(10), 
    ClientNumber int
)

INSERT INTO Solutions (SolutionName, ClientNumber) VALUES
('solution1', 111),
('solution2', 111),
('solution3', 111)
```

Then, declare the mapping table:

```
DECLARE @Temp_MasterSolutionsTable AS TABLE
(
    newSolutionID int,
    oldSolutionID int
)
```

Next, Copy the records you want:

```
MERGE INTO Solutions USING
(
    SELECT SolutionID, SolutionName, ClientNumber
    FROM Solutions
    --WHERE CONDITION -- I'm guessing you will need a where clause here
) AS s ON 1 = 0 -- Always not matched
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (SolutionName, ClientNumber)
VALUES (s.SolutionName, s.ClientNumber)
-- and here is where the magic happens
OUTPUT Inserted.SolutionID, s.SolutionID
INTO @Temp_MasterSolutionsTable (newSolutionID, oldSolutionID);
```

[See a live demo on rextester.](http://rextester.com/LVIHD3135)

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me.. Could you please check the following issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51661693/sql-merge-statement-with-input-table-name

Comment: [Glad to help :-)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291325/how-to-show-appreciation-to-a-user-on-stackoverflow/291327#291327)