# SQL Merge statement with input table name

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a scenario to copy the data from one table to another table. While copying, I need to store the Identity values of table1 and table2.

```
create procedure procedure1
(@sourceClientNumber       int,
@destinationClientNumber  int,
@statusID                 varchar(10))

as

 declare @scriptSql nvarchar(max);
declare @Temp_ClientScriptTable table
     (newScriptID int,
     oldScriptID int);

 begin

    SET @CreatedBy = 'Initaial Creation'
    SET @CreatedByName= 'Initial Creation'
    SET @CreatedDateTime = GETDATE()

 SET @scriptSql =  'Merge into [dbo].[Client_'+@destinationClientNumber +'_Script] using
                       (select  ScriptID,
                                ScriptName,
                                ScriptVersion,
                                Description,
                                FacilityID,
                                StatusID,
                                Shared,
                                ScriptTYpeID
                          from [dbo].[Client_'+@sourceClientNumber +'_Script]
                            where statusID = ' +@statusID + '                               
                       ) scripts on 1 = 0
                      When not matched then                             
                        insert ([ScriptName],
                                [ScriptVersion],
                                [CreatedBy],
                                [CreatedByName],
                                [CreatedDateTime],                          
                                [Description],
                                [FacilityID],
                                [StatusID],
                                [Shared],
                                [ScriptTypeID]) 
                         values (scripts.ScriptName,
                                 scripts.ScriptVersion,'
                                 + @CreatedBy + ','
                                 + @CreatedByName + ','
                                 + @CreatedDateTime + ',
                                 scripts.Description,
                                 scripts.FacilityID,
                                 scripts.StatusID,
                                 scripts.Shared,
                                 scripts.ScriptTypeID)
                    output Inserted.ScriptID, scripts.ScriptID
                      into' + @Temp_ClientScriptTable + '(newScriptID, oldScriptID)'                    

 EXECUTE sp_executesql @scriptSql
```

I am getting the error at @Temp_ClientScriptTable.

Could you please help me on this..

Answer (score 1):

The main problem here is faulty database design.
The fact that you have multiple tables with the same structure, only different by a number inside the name - means you are mixing data (the number) and meta data (the table name).

Instead of having a different table for each client, you should add the client number as a column to a single table.

If you can do that, it will also eliminate the need for using dynamic SQL everywhere you need to address this table.

Answer (score 0):

Root cause is, `@Temp_ClientScriptTable` is a table variable and cannot participate in string concatenation. 
Your last line of `@scriptSql` should be -

```
into @Temp_ClientScriptTable(newScriptID, oldScriptID)'
```

instead of

```
into' + @Temp_ClientScriptTable + '(newScriptID, oldScriptID)'
```

Also you need to add single quotes around varchar variables while using them in string concatenation. Your final @scriptSql will be -

```
SET @scriptSql =  'Merge into [dbo].[Client_'+@destinationClientNumber +'_Script] using
                       (select  ScriptID,
                                ScriptName,
                                ScriptVersion,
                                Description,
                                FacilityID,
                                StatusID,
                                Shared,
                                ScriptTYpeID
                          from [dbo].[Client_'+@sourceClientNumber +'_Script]
                            where statusID = ''' +@statusID + '''                               
                       ) scripts on 1 = 0
                      When not matched then                             
                        insert ([ScriptName],
                                [ScriptVersion],
                                [CreatedBy],
                                [CreatedByName],
                                [CreatedDateTime],                          
                                [Description],
                                [FacilityID],
                                [StatusID],
                                [Shared],
                                [ScriptTypeID]) 
                         values (scripts.ScriptName,
                                 scripts.ScriptVersion,'''
                                 + @CreatedBy + ''','''
                                 + @CreatedByName + ''','
                                 + @CreatedDateTime + ',
                                 scripts.Description,
                                 scripts.FacilityID,
                                 scripts.StatusID,
                                 scripts.Shared,
                                 scripts.ScriptTypeID)
                    output Inserted.ScriptID, scripts.ScriptID
                      into @Temp_ClientScriptTable(newScriptID, oldScriptID)'
```

To debug these kind of issue, you should always print the the concatenated query and see how your query will look like -

```
print @scriptSql
```